# problem running this assembly program

Tags: paging, atmel

I have this previous year exam question which i need to understand.
This uses 8bit Atmel processor

Can you explain to me what would happen?

Image file : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sv6fJ.jpg

Please view image file for clear description of the problem.

Thank you very much!

Comment: It would probably help if you mentioned which CPU family this question relates to

Comment: uses atmel processor 8bit registry

Comment: Please update your question and tag accordingly

Comment: The answer should be immediately apparent from the image link.

Comment: I am thinking it got something to do with loop and dec? I am newbie in assembly language.

Comment: ...but you will never figure it out from your typed summary

Comment: Still unable to figure it out on how to rearrange it :(

Comment: It's only incidentally an assembly language question - the real topic is memory paging.  Presumably there's some coverage of that in you notes / lecture handouts / textbook / wikipedia?

Comment: I don't know how to link it with memory paging and this question.

Comment: Whoever wrote this exam wants you to understand memory paging, so it would be a good idea to go do some reading on it.  Then the answer will be quite clear.

Comment: @student: read the part of the question again where it says that the process is only allowed to have one page in memory at a time...

Answer (score 0):

The exam question says "this process is only allowed to have one page in main memory".

1. The program takes two pages.  If a process can only have one page in memory, what does that imply?
2. Where in the program does the break between pages fall?  What is the program doing on either side of the break?
3. Given the answers to (1) and (2), what does that mean for the efficiency of the program?
4. Given (3), where might you want the page break to fall?
5. How could you change where in the program the page break is?